# Elasticsearch: count documents from query match

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I would like to get the number of documents that matches a specific string within a time range.

How can I specify a time range from this query?

```
GET myindex/_count
{
  "query": {
            "match" : {
            "log" : "ERROR"
        }
  }
}
```

To get a time range:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "msgSubmissionTime": {
        "gte": "now-10m",
        "lt": "now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to combine both queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys above me are correct, but they both added redundant  `[`,`]` for the `must` which implies a query of more than on match field.

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "match" : {  "log": "ERROR" }
      },
     "filter": 
        {
          "range": {
            "msgSubmissionTime": {
               "gte": "now-10m",
               "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot! Had to use `time` instead of `msgSubmissionTime` for my case but it works.

Comment: Happy to hear(:

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.
It can be done in two ways: with filtering and boolean query.

Elastic recommends to use filters to prefilter results - they are faster then queries.

Boolean queries can geather different queries by AND, OR, NOT operators.

In official Elastic docs you can find example that almost fits your question - [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html)

So your query will be like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "log": "ERROR"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "msgSubmissionTime": {
            "gte": "now-10m",
            "lte": "now"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "msgSubmissionTime": {
            "gte": "now-10m",
            "lt": "now"
          }
        }
      },
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "log" : "ERROR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```